# gcm gem throws MismatchSenderId from Android GCM

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am using gcm gem for sending android push notification from rails app.The error I am getting from rails console is

> {:body=>"{\"multicast_id\":5375003398127853487,\"success\":0,\"failure\":1,\"canonical_ids\":0,\"results\":[{\"error\":\"MismatchSenderId\"}]}",
>   :headers=>{"content-type"=>["application/json; charset=UTF-8"],
>   "date"=>["Mon, 07 Mar 2016 12:47:23 GMT"], "expires"=>["Mon, 07 Mar
>   2016 12:47:23 GMT"], "cache-control"=>["private, max-age=0"],
>   "x-content-type-options"=>["nosniff"],
>   "x-frame-options"=>["SAMEORIGIN"], "x-xss-protection"=>["1;
>   mode=block"], "server"=>["GSE"],
>   "alternate-protocol"=>["443:quic,p=1"], "alt-svc"=>["quic=\":443\";
>   ma=2592000; v=\"30,29,28,27,26,25\""], "accept-ranges"=>["none"],
>   "vary"=>["Accept-Encoding"], "connection"=>["close"]},
>   :status_code=>200, :response=>"success", :canonical_ids=>[],
>   :not_registered_ids=>[]}

please help me to figure out

Comment: I have found that the registration id I was using previously was incorrect .After I have put the correct id I am getting the response as success but no push is coming into the android device.

Comment: {\"multicast_id\":5378715674590080992,\"success\":1,\"failure\":0,\"canonical_ids\":0,\"results\":[{\"message_id\":\"0:1457360447424574%473c9dc2f9fd7ecd\"}]}" I am getting this response though the push is not coming to the android.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the following is met:

1. The JSON file you downloaded from Google Developer site is placed in `/app` directory
2. The registration service started and returned a non-null value for registration key
3. The listener service is setup correctly, and the `onMessageReceived` method is setup as desired, so that the notification will be created and shown.

The sample project supplied by Google actually gives the minimal setup requirements for the notification to work properly. [Refer Here](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart)

Comment: I doubt whether the problem is from the rails application end or the android app which suppose to get push notification because from rails end we are using gcm gem to call the GCM SERVER and getting the above success message but the android app is not getting the push  notification but from another PHP application with the same api_key and registration id the GCM SERVER  has been called and push notification is coming to the android app.Please help me out to figure out the problem.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to re-register the android app with new registration id, and give it another shot from both rails and php apps, each with different message.
And from android end, check when the `onMessageReceived` method is called and with which message.

Comment: when the onMessageReceived method is getting called, it is getting called with the message sent from the php apps no message is coming from the rails app though on the rails side it is showing success.Please help me to figure out @ Abdul-Rahman Ahmad

Comment: Can you share the method where you create the GCM notification on rails server?
And try to enforce content type as JSON `content_type: "application/json"` in the `options` attribute.